# Safari dev tools crashes itself and the app in iOS device/simulator with error WebCore Worker EXEC Bad Access?

Tags: ios, safari, safari-web-inspector

When I try to debug my ionic based cordova app installed in iOS device using Safari's developer tools, it crashes with error WebCore  Worker EXEC Bad Access. 
Below is the screen shot.

Safari Version: 11.0
iOS Version: 10.3.3

Screen shot of the crash:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After inspecting came to know that there is some default bug in Safari with this combination. After commenting out web worker code, I don't see the crash.